# Locking an object

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a class structure as below

```
public class Logger
{
    StremWriter sw;

    public Logger()
    {
        sw = new streamwriter(tempPath);
    }

    public StreamWriter StreamLog 
   {
        get { return sw; }
    }

}
```

i am wondering how to properly lock if I try and access the `StreamWriter` object from two different threads. Is the locking as shown below acceptable? Or should I lock the `StreamWriter` directly

```
//Log is an instance of Logger that could be accessed from multiple threads
lock (Log) {
    Log.StreamLog.WriteLine("temp");
}
```

Edit: These log objects would be going in a `ConcurrentQueue` from where different threads could retrieve them

Comment: I doubt that you have a `StremWriter`. Always post accurate code, compile first and then Copy/Paste.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was directly typing here, to be concise. But point taken, will compile in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the locking as shown below acceptable? Or should I lock the StreamWriter directl

Neither is particularly safe.  It would be far more safe/secure to handle this within your class itself.  Instead of exposing the `StreamWriter` to the outside world, make your own `WriteLine` method, and handle the locking internally.  This makes it impossible to avoid the lock by accident.

For example, something like:

```
public class Logger
{
    // Make an object to use for locking
    private readonly object syncObj = new object();

    StremWriter sw;

    public Logger()
    {
        sw = new streamwriter(tempPath);
    }

    public void WriteLine(string textToOutput) 
    {
        lock(syncObj)
            sw.WriteLine(textToOutput);
    }
}
```